# How to access authenticated GraphQL API from Nuxt frontend

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have an authenticated GraphQL API endpoint created using Appsync and Cognito (basic email and password authentication).
How I can connect to this API from an existing Nuxt frontend application? I don't want to use the default vue frontend created by aws amplify.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open AWS AppSync GUI
2. click APIs
3. select your appbackend
4. Open Integrate with your app
5. Click on Javascript tab
6. copy that cli commands and run them (from your Nuxt frontend app's root)